# Any ideas for "Adults 50+"

Tags: logo

I need to create a logo for "Adults 50+" program. This is sort of a general activity club/program for folks over 50 years old.  Logo needs to reflect an active life style of adults, rather than them preparing them for eternity.

Any ideas what can be done with it?

Comment: Adults 50+ club designed for preparing the members for eternity — well that would be a solid source of income for about 30 years from membership fees! :-D

Comment: Don't forget to leave us some feedback about how you get on with this project. :-)

Comment: It's taken me three days to pluck up the courage to click onto this question on my work computer. 'Adults 50+' brings up all kind of unwanted images in my mind!

Answer (score 5):

Get your idea juice flowing this way: select two or three activities that are representative of the program as a whole. That could be golf, jogging, extreme kickboxing (joke), whatever. Play around with the standard signage icons for those and "50+" in a few suitable fonts. You might end up going in a completely different direction, but this should break the logjam.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by studying the big (positive) movements and trends that were *pop* or maybe even rebellious something around 30 years ago — when your target group was young and restless (twentysomething) — and pick some object or element that you feel to capture the ethos. So like the trends of 1975-1980, depending on how big is the `+` in 50+, you might want to go even further. Music, fashion, TV, movies, maybe even politics are good sources for these.

While rebelliousness may evoke some good, active spirit; 50+ are usually comfort-oriented folk that value easiness over many things — so [Dr. Strangelove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)* references might be double-edged.

Try to be as local as possible. If the global trends from the history book didn't touch your area, don't try to depict them.

Be aware of possible (maybe unintentional) gender biases: being part of a gender might be more of an issue for the 50+ than it generally is for 20+.

Also try to choose something that belongs to their generation and their generation only. For example, copyright issues aside, some sort of a "Jedi Club" -reference would work better if there was no later franchise (movies, games, cartoons, you name it) — while the original trilogy started in 1977, it may feel too 2000ish than 1975-1980ish.

<sub>*) Oh well, it's from 1964, but you get the idea</sub>

Comment: Right on, man! I *always* wanted to be part of gender... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would start by studying the target audience.

50+ are:

- thinking about retirement,
- close to retirement or,
- already retired
- A lot of them are healthy, alert and young at heart, maybe they don't want to know
  they're aging.

Maybe, for those people, retirement sounds a lot like freedom. I think they are far from thinking about the end, they're taking a new beginning. They are about to fly away from professionnal obligations and just have fun living their lives. I think I would brainstorm on all those things that make us feel free.